# bulk file renaming in bash, to remove name with spaces, leaving trailing digits

Tags: regex, bash, shell

Can a bash/shell expert help me in this? Each time I use PDF to split large pdf file (say its name is `X.pdf`) into separate pages, where each page is one pdf file, it creates files with this pattern

```
"X 1.pdf"
"X 2.pdf"
"X 3.pdf"  etc...
```

The file name "X" above is the original file name, which can be anything. It then adds one space after the name, then the page number. Page numbers always start from 1 and up to how many pages. There is no option in adobe PDF to change this.

I need to run a shell command to simply remove/strip out all the "X " part, and just leave the digits, like this

```
1.pdf
2.pdf
3.pdf 
....
100.pdf  ...etc..
```

Not being good in pattern matching, not sure what regular expression I need.

I know I need something like

```
for i in *.pdf; do mv "$i$"  ........;  done
```

And it is the `.......` part I do not know how to do.

This only needs to run on Linux/Unix system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use sed..

```
for i in *.pdf; do mv "$i" $(sed 's/.*[[:blank:]]//' <<< "$i");  done
```

And it would be simple through `rename`

```
rename 's/.*\s//' *.pdf
```

Comment: Unfortunately there are several flavors of `rename` utilities, and e.g. the one that comes with `util-linux` doesn't work like that at all. You need the rename called "perl rename" for this to work.

Answer (score 4):

You can [remove](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100#Removing_part_of_a_string) everything up to (including) the last space in the variable with this:

```
${i##* }
```

That's "star space" after the double hash, meaning "anything followed by space". `${i#* }` would remove up to the first space.

So run this to check:

```
for i in *.pdf; do echo mv -i -- "$i" "${i##* }" ; done
```

and remove the `echo` if it looks good. The `-i` suggested by [Gordon Davisson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/89817/gordon-davisson) will prompt you before overwriting, and `--` signifies  end of options, which prevents things from blowing up if you ever have filenames starting with `-`.

Comment: I always recommend using `mv -i` for this sort of thing -- it'll warn you if  moving the file will overwrite another file (i.e. the last set of PDFs you converted) rather than just blindly overwriting it.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to do bulk renaming of files (or directories) and don't mind using external tools, then here's mine: [rnm](https://github.com/neurobin/rnm)

The command to do what you want would be:

```
rnm -rs '/.*\s//' *.pdf
```

`.*\s` selects the part before (and with) the last white space and replaces it with empty string.

**Note:**

1. It doesn't overwrite any existing files (throws warning if it finds an existing file with the target name).
2. And this operation is failsafe. You can get back the changes made by last `rnm` command with `rnm -u`.
3. [Here's a list of documents for `rnm`](http://neurobin.org/docs/linux/rnm/).